# Open main menu on click and subcategories on hover

Tags: magento2, jquery, magento2.4.5

After magento upgrading to `2.4.5-p3` this doesn't work anymore.
I want customers to be able to open the `main menu` on click and then continue to navigate the `subcategories` (and `sub-sub categories`) via hover.

Now I can only make it work (for ALL categories) either only by click or only by hover.
For some reason, I can't prevent the hover functionality from running.

How to make this work?